# How do I surround text beginning with ! until end of line with escape characters in sed?

Tags: regex, sed, freebsd

I want to:

1. prefix text beginning with a `!` character in a line with `ESC E` (being `ESC` octal code `\033`)
2. suffix above text with `ESC F` at the end of the line.

This is what I have tried:

```
sed $'s/\(!.*\)/\033E\1\033F/'
```

This is the error I get:

```
$ echo "test line     ! This part shall be enclosed with ESC commands" | sed $'s/\(!.*\)/\033E\1\033F/'
sh: Syntax error: Bad escape sequence
```

If I remove the `$` sign it can be seen that the text is detected and enclosed, but `sed` is not being able to insert the `ESC` characters.

```
$ echo "test line     ! This part shall be enclosed with ESC commands" | sed 's/\(!.*\)/\033E\1\033F/'
test line     033E! This part shall be enclosed with ESC commands033F
```

I am using FreeBSD 12 `sed` which is expected to be a superset of the IEEE Std 1003.2 POSIC.2 specification according to the man page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `$'..'` only for the required portion:

```sh
$ s='test line     ! This part shall be enclosed with ESC commands'
$ echo "$s" | sed 's/\(!.*\)/'$'\033''E\1'$'\033F''/' | cat -v
test line     ^[E! This part shall be enclosed with ESC commands^[F
```

Not sure about other versions, but on `GNU sed`, you can use hexadecimal `\xHH` and octal `\oNNN` (note the `o`) escapes directly, so you can do:

```sh
$ echo "$s" | sed 's/\(!.*\)/\x1BE\1\x1BF/' | cat -v
test line     ^[E! This part shall be enclosed with ESC commands^[F

$ echo "$s" | sed 's/\(!.*\)/\o033E\1\o033F/' | cat -v
test line     ^[E! This part shall be enclosed with ESC commands^[F
```